# How to run PS1(powerShell Script) files with C++

Tags: c++, powershell

I am making a toast notification apear, but when the script runs it just closes the powershell like if it ran it but no noticfication apears. How could I make it work?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
       string strPath = "d:\\callPowerShell.ps1";
              system("start powershell.exe d:\\callPowerShell.ps1");
}
```

It would recall the file and run it on PowerShell

Comment: You can try to remove the `start` prefix to see more clearly the output from powershell.exe  (It might help to spot the error cause). For example on my PC it enabled me to see the error message: _"... cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system."_

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I made an app in C++Builder and I did something like that for made a backup in MariaDB. The code I used was something like this:

```
    UnicodeString usMysqldump, usCmd;

usMysqldump = "In my case path to mysqldump.exe";
usCmd = "Script to be executed";

ShellExecuteW( Application->Handle, "open", usMysqldump, usCmd, NULL, SW_HIDE  );
```

PD: SW_HIDE is for keep the console hide, may be you want something diferent.

Try this code and I hope it be helpfull for you.

Comment: so would I need to change it to
``
    UnicodeString usPowershell, usCmd;

usPowershell= "powershell.exe";
usCmd = "toast.ps1";

ShellExecuteW( Application->Handle, "open", usPowershell, usCmd, NULL, SW_HIDE  );
``

Comment: That work for me, but you may using a different enviroment that don't use UnicodeString,  if you are using another IDE it could not be the same. You can try to use String or char[] and make the needed cast, if necessary.